# Kong with ModSecurity on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kong-plugin, ingress-nginx, kong-ingress, kubernetes-gateway-api

We (likely newbie) recently started to use [Kong Gateway](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/3.5.x/install/kubernetes/helm-quickstart/) to expose services to internet. Earlier we were using [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and on the top of it, we install [ModSecurity](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/third-party-addons/modsecurity/) in order to implement some security rules for exposed APIs.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-app-ext
  namespace: kong
  annotations:
    konghq.com/protocols: "https"
    konghq.com/https-redirect-status-code: "308"
    konghq.com/plugins: "app-user-ext-acl, rate-limit-ext"
```

Considering **Kong is built on top of Nginx**, is this advisable to use kong and modsecurity annotations together in a same Ingress object? If not, please enlighten. Or any kong plugin available to achieve the same?

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-modsecurity: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-owasp-core-rules: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/modsecurity-snippet: |
      SecRuleEngine On
```